# Nginx PHP5-FPM Bad Gateway 502

Tags: nginx, apc, php

I implemented a new php class which concats PDF documents into one file. At my dev local server, everything works fine. After pushing it to my production server, i'm running into a "Bad Gateway" error.

```
/var/log/php5-fpm.log:

4-Mär-2014 11:20:54] WARNING: [pool www] child 17386 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 10.380074 seconds from start

/var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log:

2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 recv: fd:7 -1 of 4096
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [error] 18761#0: *613 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.200.179.25, server: example.com,  request: "GET /documents/pdf_generator/140183/en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://booker.visioncode.de/documents/overview"
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 http next upstream, 2
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 free rr peer 1 4
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 finalize http upstream request: 502
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 finalize http fastcgi request
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 close http upstream connection: 7
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 free: 00000000017204E0, unused: 48
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 event timer del: 7: 1395659005493
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 reusable connection: 0
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 http finalize request: 502, "/index.php?/documents/pdf_generator/140183/en" a:1, c:1
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 http special response: 502, "/index.php?/documents/pdf_generator/140183/en"
2014/03/24 11:58:25 [debug] 18761#0: *613 HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
```

I'm google for about 3 hours and modify a lot of memory and timeout settings, but still the same error. I updated all versions to the ones running on my dev local machine - no changes.

But when I "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload", I can access the script always ONE TIME after doing it (PDF will be generated and no error output). If I try to call the pdf generator again, it returns to "Bad gateway".

What could be wrong???

Comment: Is that the only line in your php5-fpm log file? Could you configure php5-fpm to maybe log a bit more?

Comment: it's the only output if I trigger the error, but I alread put "debug" on .. how should I set it up? [24-Mär-2014 12:34:45] WARNING: [pool www] child 19410 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 1379.308037 seconds from start
[24-Mär-2014 12:34:45] NOTICE: [pool www] child 20529 started

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I thought it was unrelated, because your question shows a log from March 4th.

Comment: Ah ya, you are right .. same error, but any other reason at this time ;) do you have any idea to this error? I guess it must have something to do with memory/session limits because I can execute the script always one time after I reload the php5-fpm daemon.

Comment: I'm one step closer .. if I trigger apc_clear_cache(); before each execution, I can submit it without any problems. So, the problem is located at the APC. Any ideas which setting can cause this issues???? APC Version 3.1.13, PHP 5.4.26

Comment: Since you're getting a core dump, and it works one time (when loading the apc cache initially), you're almost certainly running into an APC bug. I'd suggest using a different opcode cache, http://php.net/opcache, xcache etc.

Comment: Good job on getting closer to the source of the problem. But one formality: could you please retract your answer (as it isn't really the answer to your problem) and instead edit your question to include this update? If you solve your problem, you are of course highly encouraged to post an answer to your question. Also, @Avibodha's suggestion sounds reasonable. Please try and disable APC and look if the problem persists.